# Multiple inheritance, virtual methods collision and pointers from base classes

Tags: c++, polymorphism, language-lawyer, multiple-inheritance

I have a result that I didn't expect from multiple inheritance, `virtual` methods and pointers to base classes.

---

With `d.getStr()`, when `d` is a `derived` instance, the `base_2` version is called, as I expected.

With `p->getStr()`, when `p` is a pointer to a `derived` instance (or a pointer to `base_2` pointing to a `derived` instance), the `base_2` version is called, as I expected.

But with `p->getStr()`, when `p` is a pointer to a `base_1` pointing to a `derived` instance, the `base_1` version is called and I was convinced would be called the `base_2` version (thanks the `using` and the fact that `getStr()` are `virtual` methods).

The following is a simple example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base_1
{
   virtual std::string getStr () const
    { return "string from base 1"; }
};

struct base_2
{
   virtual std::string getStr () const
    { return "string from base 2"; }
};

struct derived : public base_1, public base_2
{ 
   using base_2::getStr;
};


int main ()
{
   derived  d;

   derived *  dp  = &d;
   base_1 *   bp1 = &d;
   base_2 *   bp2 = &d;

   std::cout << "from derived:         " << d.getStr() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "from derived pointer: " << dp->getStr() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "from base_1 pointer:  " << bp1->getStr() << std::endl;
   std::cout << "from base_2 pointer:  " << bp2->getStr() << std::endl;
}
```

The output is the following

```
from derived:         string from base 2
from derived pointer: string from base 2
from base_1 pointer:  string from base 1
from base_2 pointer:  string from base 2
```

I know that, to impose the call of `base_2` version, I can add in `derived` the following method

```
std::string getStr () const
 { return base_2::getStr(); }
```

but my questions are:

1) Why does the pointer to `base_1` (pointing to a derived instance) ignore the `using` directive and call the `base_1` version of `getStr()`?

2) Is there a way to impose the `base_2` version of `getStr()`, when `derived` instance is used by a `base_1` pointer, without redefining `getStr()`?

**--- EDIT ---**

Thanks for the answers.

I understand that you are describing what's happening but my doubt is: does the language (the standard) describe this aspect? Or is it an undefined part?

I mean: if I remove the `using` directive, I get a compilation error (`error: request for member getStr is ambiguous`), from `d.getStr()` and from `dp->getStr()`, because the compiler doesn't know which version of `getStr()` to chose.

But `getStr()` are `virtual` methods. So (I was convinced that) a base pointer should use the derived version of they. But we have a couple of colliding methods.

From the language (standard) point of view, a `base_1` (or `base_2`) is the pointer authorized (or obligated) to choose one of the two versions of the colliding methods ignoring the other?

Maybe I'm wrong but seems to me that, in this way, the `virtual` methods are managed as non `virtual` methods.

Comment: `using` only helps in visibity. It does not make derived `overload` the base virtual function or look like it.

Answer (score 4):

You are expecting that when you using the `using` keyword in the following manner:

```
struct derived : public base_1, public base_2
{ 
   using base_2::getStr;
};
```

That this is the same as:

```
struct derived : public base_1, public base_2
{
   void getStr()
   {
        base_2::getStr();
   }
};
```

In this case, the behavior you are expecting -- invoking `p->getStr()`, when p is a pointer to a `base_1` -- would, indeed, end up invoking `base_2::getStr()`. `derived` overrides `base_1`'s `getStr()`, so invoking `base_1`'s `getStr`(), through an ordinary pointer, results in `derived`'s `getStr`() getting invoked, which invokes `base_2` `getStr()` method.

However, this is not what happens. The `using` keyword is not an alias for forwarding a method call in this manner. The `using` keyword does not create a method in `derived`'d class, so class inheritance is not affected, and `derived_1`'s `getStr()` does not get overriden in the subclsas. And that's why invoking `derived_1`'s `getStr()` does not wind up invoking `derived_2`'s `getStr()`.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because the derived class has to have 2 vtable entries for `getStr()`, one for each base class, so it can correctly resolve both `base_1::getStr()` and `base_2::getStr()`. The `using` directive doesn't create a `derived::getStr()` vtable entry or replace the base-class ones, it just selects which base-class entry will be used. When going through a pointer to `base_1`, the compiler only "sees" the vtable entries for virtual functions from `derived` and `base_1` so it resolves `getStr()` to `base_1::getStr()`. Your solution of adding an explicit `getStr()` in `derived` is probably the cleanest one, although it might be advisable to make it virtual to match the base classes for clarity.

Comment: thanks for the answer; my doubt is: the 2 vtables in derived class are imposed by the C++ standard or are a implementation detail? In other word: this happen because it's imposed by the standard or is other compilers are authorized to generate a different behaviour?

Comment: The mechanics are an implementation detail, but because the base classes may themselves be derived classes with virtual methods the end results have to work out pretty much the same no matter the exact mechanism. The only alternative is for the compiler to see all the code and be able to figure out what the actual type of the object pointed to is, which is highly non-trivial.

Answer (score 0):

1) Seems like your code is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. You point to base_1, so you get functions from base_1 (or any of its base classes). That the object is made up of both base_1 and base_2 is unknown at that point, because you are point to a base class, not a derived class.

2) No, that is simply impossible. You must indeed overload getStr() in `derived`.

Comment: thanks for the anser but, about point (1), you're describing the behaviour of base/derived classes with normal methods; `getStr()` is are `virtual` methods

Comment: That doesn't matter; the fact is that virtual functions can "jump" from classes that are side by side, only vertical if you draw a class-relation diagram.