# Store object as it's base VIRTUAL class

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance

Why can't one store an object as it's base virtual class ?

Consider the following example : It will segfault if `Derived` inherits ***virtually*** of `Base`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    int baseInt = 42;
};

class Derived : public /* virtual */ Base  // <<< Uncomment the virtual to get a segfault
{
public:
    int derivedInt = 84;
};


int main()
{
    Base *base_ptr = new Derived();

    Derived *derived_ptr = reinterpret_cast<Derived *>(base_ptr);

    std::cout << "  baseInt is "    << derived_ptr->baseInt 
              << ", derivedInt is " << derived_ptr->derivedInt << std::endl; // segv on this line
}
```

Comment: You need to `static_cast`, not `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: I get the following error with static_cast and c-style cast : `cannot convert from pointer to base class ‘Base’ to pointer to derived class ‘Derived’ because the base is virtual`

Comment: Apologies, you need to even use `dynamic_cast`, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52245017/1548468) explains.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [diamond inheritance virtual member casting with pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52244794/diamond-inheritance-virtual-member-casting-with-pointers)

Comment: dynamic_cast gives me the following error `error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘base_ptr’ (of type ‘class Base*’) to type ‘class Derived*’ (source type is not polymorphic)`

Comment: Add a virtual destructor to `Base` to make it polymorphic.

Comment: That works. I'm adding the virtual destructor to the question, do you mind writing your answer so I can accept it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `reinterpret_cast` you used simply uses the `Base` pointer *as if it were a `Derived` pointer*.

Instead, this is one of the few situations where you should use a `dynamic_cast`.
The example in [the documentation for `dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) shows such a downcast.